# Не получается сделать merge - "Already up to date"

Tags: git, merge

Запутался в гите. Итак, веду локальную разработку в PhpStorm. Есть удаленный репозиторий, там две ветки: dev и master. В настойках PhpStorm привязал к проекту данный репозиторий. Все небольшие изменения отправляю коммитами в dev-ветку через push. На сервере, где хостится проект, я из ветки master удаленного репозитория сделаю единоразово clone и далее регулярно  буду делать pull. Сейчас все изменения накапливаются в dev-ветке в виде мелких коммитов.
Чего я хочу добиться:

1. сливать изменения из dev в master
2. и чтобы при этом все новые коммиты преобразовывались в один крупный (после слияния мелкие коммиты так и остаются в dev, а в master возникает один новый результирующий коммит)

Застрял уже на шаге 1: merge не работает
Запускал такие команды:

1. git checkout master
   результат:
   Already on 'master'
   Your branch is up to date with 'dev/dev'.
2. git status
   результат:
   On branch master
   Your branch is up to date with 'dev/dev'.
   nothing to commit, working tree clean
3. git merge dev
   результат:
   merge: dev - not something we can merge
   Did you mean this? dev/dev
4. git merge dev/dev
   результат:
   Already up to date.

Подозреваю, что все эти команды гит пытается выполнить на локальном хранилище, а не на удаленном (там ничего не добавилось в ветку в master, при этом в dev есть 5 новых коммитов).
И смущает, что везде пишется dev/dev, а не просто dev.
Подскажите, что я сделал не так?

Comment: Еще раз. А то много написано. Вы хотите выполнять таски в своих ветках и мержить их в develop (например для тестирования фич). После чего вы хотите уже готовые изминения мержить с develop в master. Если я все верно понял, то не понятна проблема. Запись  `Already on 'master'` напугала? Так может оно так и есть ) Гит обычно не врет. Если вы так боитесь что локальная с удаленной не совпадает то сделайте `git pull`.

Comment: что покажет команда git remote -v ?